# Access the element of a list with map based on permutations of the indices

Tags: python, list, dictionary, permutation, indices

What I want, is to access the elements with a list of pairs of indexes from all permutations with `map`, without using `for` loops:

Starting code:

```
from itertools import permutations

# string list     
n=['foo','asda','bar','words']  

# pair permutation object
index = permutations(range(0,len(n)), 2)

list(index)
Out[0]:[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
```

So, by using `map` I would like to get like the following code the element, in this case is made with `for` loops:

```
for idx in index:
    i=n[idx[0]]
    j=n[idx[1]]
    print ((i,j))
```

Desired output (if you run the previous example):

```
('foo', 'asda')
('foo', 'bar')
('foo', 'words')
('asda', 'foo')
('asda', 'bar')
('asda', 'words')
('bar', 'foo')
('bar', 'asda')
('bar', 'words')
('words', 'foo')
('words', 'asda')
('words', 'bar)
```

Comment: What is the output you want exactly?

Comment: The output would be a list of vectors, with all these permutations  by using map not with for loops neither list comprehesion

Comment: Isn't what you want just `list(permutations(n, 2))`?

Comment: Why are you against for loop?

Comment: I im trying to iterate over a very massive list, and transform every for loop into a map, because it is supposed to be faster by using spark and parallelize all this operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create the permutations of a list instead of the indices:

```
from itertools import permutations

n=['foo','asda','bar','words']  
index = list(permutations(n, 2))
print(index)
```

prints:

```
[('foo', 'asda'),
 ('foo', 'bar'),
 ('foo', 'words'),
 ('asda', 'foo'),
 ('asda', 'bar'),
 ('asda', 'words'),
 ('bar', 'foo'),
 ('bar', 'asda'),
 ('bar', 'words'),
 ('words', 'foo'),
 ('words', 'asda'),
 ('words', 'bar')]
```

If you want to just "print" them you can use `map` with `print`. Although it's kind of ugly to use a `map` for it's side-effects but it seems to do what you want:

```
from __future__ import print_function
_ = list(map(print, index))
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if I understood what you need, but this gives same output with `map`:

```
for i in map(lambda x: (n[x[0]], n[x[1]], total_len(n[x[0]], n[x[1]])), index):
    print i
#('foo', 'asda', 7)
#('foo', 'bar', 6)
#('foo', 'words', 8)
#('asda', 'foo', 7)
#('asda', 'bar', 7)
#('asda', 'words', 9)
#('bar', 'foo', 6)
#('bar', 'asda', 7)
#('bar', 'words', 8)
#('words', 'foo', 8)
#('words', 'asda', 9)
#('words', 'bar', 8)
```

And to remove `total_len` you can use:

```
map(lambda x: (n[x[0]], n[x[1]]), index)
```

Note: If you are using python 3.x `map()` returns iterator, unlike python 2.x where it returns `list`, so you will need to convert it into a `list()`.

And, just so you know, this works perfectly as well:

```
list(permutations(n, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The nearest I can get to that is:

```
 from itertools import permutations

 # string list     
 n=['foo','asda','bar','words']  

# pair permutation object
index = permutations(xrange(0,len(n)), 2)

  list(zip(n, n, range(4)))*3
```

Output:

```
  [('foo', 'foo', 0),
  ('asda', 'asda', 1),
  ('bar', 'bar', 2),
  ('words', 'words', 3),
  ('foo', 'foo', 0),
  ('asda', 'asda', 1),
  ('bar', 'bar', 2),
  ('words', 'words', 3),
  ('foo', 'foo', 0),
  ('asda', 'asda', 1),
  ('bar', 'bar', 2),
  ('words', 'words', 3)]
```